# Summing the image matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to matlab . Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this snippet for summing the 3-D array of image.Its showing error in 3rd line and I am unable to debug it.

```
x=imread('test.jpg');
imshow(x);
sumdiff=sum(sum(sum(testArr2, 3),2),1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that strikes me as obviously wrong is that you are summing over the values in a variable called `testArr2` but have the image pixel data in a variable called `x`.  Where does `testArr2` get defined and populated with data ?

Answer (score 3):

While Mark had probably answered the question, I wanted to add that the easiest way to sum over the entire array is probably using the colon syntax:

```
sum_all = sum(x(:))
```

Also note that `imread` usually returns an array of integers (`uint8` for standard jpeg images). Not all mathematical operations are allowed when using this type of arrays - and sometimes using `im2double` is necessary.